# Applescript to Embed Fonts in Multiple EPS Files

Tags: javascript, applescript, adobe, embed, adobe-illustrator

I am looking to embed fonts in a batch of Illustrator EPS files rather than opening up each one and saving as and clicking "Embed Fonts (for other applications)"
I would like an Applescript that could do this, I prefer Applescripts over recording actions because they seem to be less clunky.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked into batch processing? It may do exactly what you want

Comment: I guess I thought of a script changing something in multiple files as a way to accomplish batch processing but I am looking into it, thank you

Comment: Take a look at the AppleScript Reference documentation for Illustrator. (They can be found [here](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)). In the _"EPS save options object properties"_ section on page 50 it lists the `embed all fonts` option which accepts a Boolean value.

Comment: I did see that and think it was interesting, I'm still trying to figure out how to incorporate into a script with some intense Googling but I haven't yet. I am not a real programmer, just a DTP person trying to figure out how to get things done faster, but I will definitely look into this more.